# Zen Cart :: coupons - is there a way to create a page that will pull in the existing coupons and display them?

Tags: php, zen-cart

Zen Cart :: coupons - is there a way to create a page that will pull in the existing coupons and display them?

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you mean a public (catalog) page.

I have never done it, but just in case it helps, I would start by looking at the file /includes/modules/pages/discount_coupon/header.php. This header gets the coupon id from the POST and retrieves its data from DB.

So it seems moderately easy to just duplicate this folder, rename it as "discount_coupons_list", modify the header.php to allow for a loop and do the rest of minor modifications that you would need to add any new page to Zen Cart ([instructions here](http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Creating_new_pages)). For the template file, you could also use tpl_discount_coupon_default.php as a starting point.